# Boolean Matrices and Transpose

Tags: digital-logic

How can one find the Transpose of a Boolean Matrix? Also how does one interpret the logical circuit represented by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose of a Matrix can be given below.

For example, suppose matrix is as below:

1   1   1   1

0   1   0   1

0   0   1   0

0   0   0   1

Transpose of the matrix can be given below (Flip Across diagonally):

1   0   0   0

1   1   0   0

1   0   1   0

1   1   0   1

Now keep this matrix on K-MAP As shown in fig below:

[image]

So the expression can be given as:

[image]

Circuit can be given as below:

[image]